# Can't explain exception in number formatting

Tags: java, number-formatting

I have this function:

```
static private DecimalFormat df1 = new DecimalFormat("#0.###############",
        new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US));
static private DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat(
        "0.0##############E000", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US));

    public static String toChar(final double val) {
        String cont = Double.toString(val);
        final String f1 = df1.format(val);
        final String f2 = df2.format(val);
        try {
            final double v1 = df1.parse(f1).doubleValue();
            final double v2 = df2.parse(f2).doubleValue();
            if (Math.abs(v1 - val) <= Math.abs(v2 - val) && f1.length() < 16) {
                // 6.0 -> 6
                cont = f1;
            } else {
                final int j = f2.indexOf('E');
                if (f2.charAt(j + 1) == '-') {
                    cont = f2.substring(0, j - 1) + "e" + f2.substring(j + 1);
                } else {
                    cont = f2.substring(0, j - 1) + "e+" + f2.substring(j + 1);
                }
            }
        } catch (final ParseException e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
        return cont;
    }
```

Now, the strange fact is that one of our clients was able to get an exception from this code:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -2
Begin trace of call stack:
Level  0:    String.substring(..) {java.lang.String.java, -1}
Level  1:    Functions.toChar(..) {....runtime.Functions.java, 1579}
...
```

Line number 1579 refers to the second substring is the code snippet. I could get this result if variable `f2` would not have an "E" in it, but I wasn't able to provide any input which would do so.

Does anyone of you see the problem that we are overlooking here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens when you pass `Double.NaN` like this:

```
toChar(Double.NaN);
```

(might be other values and ranges that produce the same), thus just do:

```
public static String toChar(final double val) {
    if(Double.isNaN(val)) {
        return "NaN";
    }
    ...
```

Comment: @Thorsten Why you choose this answer as the correct one when other answers already said it before this one truly escapes me...

Answer (score 2):

In my unit test it fails for

```
toChar(Double.NaN);
toChar(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
toChar(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
```

The string representation of those is

```
NaN
Infinity
-Infinity
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not providing which double value actually makes this error happen, we can only guess:

`f2` has no `'E'` so `indexOf` returns `-1`, hence `j - 1 = -2`, which is an invalid index for `substring()`. You should check the return value of `indexOf`.

Comment: I don't know what number causes the error, but Double.NaN could be a good guess...

Comment: @Thorsten Debugging and/or logging are your friends.

Answer (score 0):

Check what happens if you put NaN (Not a Number - like 1/0) in the method.